# Is it possible to transfer minting authority of a Solana Token to another account?

Tags: javascript, web3js, solana, metaplex, anchor-solana

I have created a Solana NFT token using Metaplex, and mint authority is assigned to 3EnfV4qYBjH15nN5XDmW74bqWYiQQFHQCbnVrWxZLua6 by metaplex, and i need to mint more these tokens using sdk like

```
 @solana/web3.js,
 @metaplex/js and
 @solana/spl-token

Address  2NXFLubjDdJCKbhs7BQ4UJZysQWMAoKeLAZANHSbJ5hF
Mint Authority  CLm9t8qvmBHDzGZRuTQ6ybeLBgLZppj89ndG8mDvDsoA
Update Authority    8e2ATWqx9YaUcJMit2WBcVVbxVxrFmAeqcUc5qsX4zPd

Update Authority is assigned to my phantom wallet
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is! Using the Solana CLI the command would
be
`spl-token authorize <YOUR_TOKEN_PUBKEY> mint <NEW_PUB_KEY>`

You can find more info - including how to do it in JS here: https://spl.solana.com/token

Comment: Tried but this error comes 
RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0x4 [5 log messages]` @Mark